# 'bool' object has no attribute 'year

Tags: odoo, calculated-field

I have a custom field in employee module in Odoo to display the age.

That field is calculated from birtday field

```
for record in self:
    today = datetime.date.today()
    record['x_studio_age_2'] = today.year - record['birthday'].year - ((today.month, today.day) < (record['birthday'].month, record['birthday'].day))
```

The age field works, but I get an error when I try to import a CSV:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py", line 330, in safe_eval
    return unsafe_eval(c, globals_dict, locals_dict)
  File "", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'year'
```

So, i have to remove the code but now I have to update the age of all employess.

Is any wrong with the code?

Comment: What value is ```record['birthday']``` supposed to be?  Right now, it's a boolean.

Comment: birthday type is birtday

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do someting like that.
`False` means value is not set.

```py
today = datetime.date.today()
for record in self:
    if record['birthday']:
        record['x_studio_age_2'] = today.year - record['birthday'].year - ((today.month, today.day) < (record['birthday'].month, record['birthday'].day))
    else:
        record['x_studio_age_2'] = False
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to check the birthday first , because if it's not set it will return false value as boolean